# Pictured link not showing up over another picture

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I'm attempting to add a Pin It button over top of the main image of a thumbnail slideshow I have. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am wanting the Pin It button to be on the top right corner of the main image in the slideshow. I want the button to only appear in a hover state over the main image.

I created a fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/0nst2w0g/

I believe the following code is what it wrong. The slideshow works great and I am just attempting to add this on top of everything I had before.

```
*-Pin It button---*/
 .pinItButton {
    padding: 15px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.pinItButton a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
.pinItButton a:hover {
    -webkit-transition: color 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    /* property duration timing-function delay */
    -moz-transition: color 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    -o-transition: color 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    transition: color 300ms ease-in 200ms;
}
.pinItButton:hover {
    -webkit-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    /* property duration timing-function delay */
    -moz-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    -o-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
}
.slideshow .pinItButton {
    display: none;
}
.slideshow:hover .pinItbutton {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    float: right;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I have tried putting...

```
<div class="pinItButton"><a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" data-pin-height="28"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_28.png" /></a>
            </div>
```

under the Slideshow div, under the big class div. Nothing is making this appear where I want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple of things wrong. First things first:

```
.slideshow:hover .pinItbutton {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    float: right;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

That says pinItbutton, not pinItButton. Also, you are targeting your pin button with some CSS for the other images that is making it massive and weird.

Here are some fixes, but it definitely needs some work.
https://jsfiddle.net/0nst2w0g/16/

EDIT: Here is a working example with a floating slider. Not sure if this works for you. https://jsfiddle.net/0nst2w0g/20/

Comment: Thanks! How can I get it so the Pin it button stays inside of the main img. I tried adding in the class .big to the part of the CSS above the code you just posted in your answer like this... .slideshow .big .pinItButton {..........but that didn't help. Any ideas so this will work well with all screen sizes?

Comment: The reason the pin it button is not on top of the image, is that the slider div has a width that extends all the way to the right of the page. You could explicitly set your slider width to be the same width as your images, and your images would have to be all the same size. You can also float your slider, but I don't know if that works for you. Here is an example with floated slider: https://jsfiddle.net/0nst2w0g/20/

Comment: Thanks. When I added values to the Top and Right parts, it configured it how I wanted to make it look good on a desktop and mobile, so that is all I needed. I appreciate your help!